# Pylint error 'R0903: Too few public methods' and class definition style

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pylint

Look at the following code:

```
1  class MySuperClass():
2      pass
3
4
5  class MySuperClass(MySuperClass):
6      def method_one(self, x):
7          (do something)
8
9
10 class MySuperClass(MySuperClass):
11     def method_two(self, y):
12         (do something else)
13
```

Thus it creates a class definition. If I check this code with [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint), it says that at line 5 *'R0903: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)'*, and at line 10 *'R0903: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)'*.

This is not my code. Those who write it use [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) for code writing, and I guess this style is convenient for him, and as I understood, it works better with Jupyter Notebook.

I do not use Jupyter Notebook, so should I do something to fix this Pylint error, or can I leave the source code unchanged? what do you think?

What is the difference between this class definition style and the usual style?

Answer (score 2):

If the three parts are next to each other, you can just join them together;

```
class MySuperClass:

    def method_one(self, x):
        # Do something

    def method_two(self, y):
        # Do something else
```

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMortensen; that looks better!